# Improving code quality/organization of event-heavy riot applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, riot.js

I am building an application using riot.js and jquery. Everything works as expected, however as the code grows, so does my worry that triggering and handling events (.trigger/.on) in random/unexpected places in the code is doing nothing to keep my code organized and quickly understandable.

My questions are:

(1) I would like to keep code for such an application clean and streamlined (event namespaces is one thing that comes to my mind) and

(2) I would like to keep the events on the model clearly separated from events on the DOM in the presenter. How can I achieve these goals in a riot.js based application

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at a [functional reactive programming approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).
Here are some solutions you may be insterested in:

- [Rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) - The Reactive Extensions for JavaScript from Microsoft
- [Bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/) - another popular FRP library
- [Kefir.js](https://github.com/rpominov/kefir) - less popular but insteresting FRP library